# Add custom fields to shopping cart display - Ubercart 3

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

I have Drupal 7 and UC 3 running with custom fields.  I want to be able to display those fields in the shopping cart but can't seems to be able to do it. That's my first module creation attempt!

I try to use hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {} in a custom module:

```
function swcart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'uc_cart_view_form':

      // Adding Grade column
       $form['items']['#columns']['grade'] = array('cell' => 'Grade', 'weight' => 3.5);

      for($i=0; $i < count($form['items']); $i++) {
    if(isset($form['items'][$i]['nid'])) {
          // Loading the node so we can retrieve the information we need.
      $product = node_load($form['items'][$i]['nid']['#value']);

          // Adding the 'Grade' to the product that is in the user's cart.
      $form['items'][$i]['grade']['#value'] = $product -> field_product_term_data;
    }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

The column 'Grade' shows up but no data in the table.  What should I do?  Do I have to modify the TAPir table? hook an other uc_cart function?
Thanks

Comment: Manage to check if the extra field was being passed in the cart, by doing a print_r (node_load($form['items'][1]['nid']['#value'])).  I get something like minus irrelevant stuff `code`stdClass Object ( [vid] => 7270 [uid] => 1 [title] => Bai Bu ... [field_product_term_grade] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [tid] => 4 ) ) )  [field_product_botanical] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => Stemonae Radix [format] => [safe_value] => Stemonae Radix ) ) ) ... `code`  How do I get to extract **bold**[field_product_term_grade]**bold**'s value?

Comment: Anyone to help?  I left off programming about 20 years ago with pascal, but object oriented stuff now is way different than before.  I have no idea how to use stdClass objects nor access their data?  Any good tutorial around? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

This two links of Ubercart 3 API should help:
[hook_tapir_table_alter](http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!uc_store!uc_store.api.php/function/hook_tapir_table_alter/7)
[uc_cart_view_table](http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!uc_cart!uc_cart.module/function/uc_cart_view_table/7)

In the first link there's an example for adding column with data.

**EDIT:** Finished up with adding price per 1 product column by using such code. Hope this will help someone to overcome ubercart's inflexibility.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_form_uc_cart_view_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['items']['#columns']['remove']['weight'] = 6;
  $form['items']['#columns']['total']['weight'] = 5;
  $form['items']['#columns']['qty']['weight'] = 4;

  $form['items']['#columns']['price'] = array(
      'cell' => t('Price'), 
      'weight' => 3,
  );
}
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_tapir_table_alter(&$table, $table_id) {
  if ($table_id == 'uc_cart_view_table') {
    foreach (element_children($table) as $key) {
      if (!empty($table['#parameters'][1][$key]['nid'])) {
        $node = node_load($table['#parameters'][1][$key]['nid']['#value']);
        $table[$key]['price'] = array(
          '#markup' => theme('uc_product_price',array('element' => array('#value' => $node->sell_price))),
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to Drupal, Could you tell me how and where to use this code.

Comment: In the custom module. Don't forget to change YOUR_MODULE_NAME in functions names to your module name.
Tutorial on how to make your own module: https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360